# GetOriginal() returns null

Tags: c#, silverlight, entity-framework, wcf-ria-services

I'm using EF + RIA services in my Silverlight application.
The problem that I've faced is that I'm trying to compare modified entities with theirs original values before invoking `SubmitChanges` operation. But for some reason [Entity.GetOriginal()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.domainservices.client.entity.getoriginal%28v=vs.91%29.aspx) returns me null even for entity which has `EntityState == Modified`.

Here is extension method which I'm using:

```
    public static T GetOriginalEntity<T>(this T entity) where T : Entity
    {                        
        return (T)entity.GetOriginal();
    }
```

***How can I get original entity value?***

Comment: Very strange. Just to confirm, these are entities you've loaded from the database and modified in the client?

Comment: @AlastairPitts Yep. Either for modified or untouched entity I get same behavior.

Comment: I had a look at the source code for `Entity.GetOriginal()`, the only time it should return null from the Entity is if the original values are non-existent. Have you called `IRevertibleChangeTracking.RejectChanges()` or `IChangeTracking.AcceptChanges()` before calling `GetDefault()`? Can you show us a snippet of the code where your using it?